# Prolog: Min function failed

Tags: prolog

I am trying to implement a min(X,L) function such that if X is the min of the List, return true, else false.

```
min(X,[X]) :- !.
min(res, [X,Y|Z]:- (X > Y -> min(res, [Y|Z]); min(res, [X|Z])).
```

Result run:

```
min(6, [6]).
yes

min(6, [6,7,8]).
no
```

Trace:

```
1 1 Call: min(6,[6,7,8,9]) ? c
1 1 Fail: min(6,[6,7,8,9]) ? c

(4 ms) no
```

I am totally new to Prolog, any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: `res` is an atom, not a variable.

Comment: Also, your cut is not necessary. Better to avoid cuts until you know Prolog a little better.

Comment: I see, i changed res to N and it worked. thanks